# Script only writes to the first file it creates out of many?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that fetches 500 randomly picked lines from a huge file and then writes them to a different file. I wanna be able to do this n number of times so that I'll end up with many small files.

Problem is, the script I have made only writes data to the first file it creates. It creates all the other smaller files as well, but it doesn't actually write data to those files. They are just empty. What am I missing?

```py
import random

def main():
    lines_in_file = file_len('data.json')
    file_size = 500
    iterations = 10
    with open('data.json') as data_file: # open the big data file
        for iteration_count in range(iterations): # for x in range(how many files I want to make)
            picked_numbers = [] # what line numbers have been picked, to avoid duplicates
            smallfile = None # the small file written to disk
            for _ in range(file_size):
                # for x in range of how many lines I want to appear in the file
                line_num = random.randint(0, lines_in_file-1) # the line that was picked at random
                while line_num in picked_numbers: # if the line exists in the file, find another one
                    line_num = random.randint(0, lines_in_file-1)
                picked_numbers.append(line_num) # add the number to the file so we can look it up later
            small_filename = 'data_{}.json'.format(iteration_count) # create the new small file to write to
            smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
            for position, line in enumerate(data_file): # enumerate the big data file to find all the lines we have in picked_numbers
                if position in picked_numbers:
                    smallfile.write(line)
            smallfile.close()

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The code you have added does not seem to be the best way to do the job you wanted and hence is not clear. Could you add some comments to explain the code

Comment: You are missing `data_file.seek(0)` at the end of each iteration

Comment: @NobbyNobbs so after smallfile.close ?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs Yeah that did it. Thanks! Do you wanna make it an answer so you can get the accepted answer?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't worth it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `data_file.seek(0)` at the end of each iteration

```
import random

def main():
    lines_in_file = file_len('data.json')
    file_size = 500
    iterations = 10
    with open('data.json') as data_file: # open the big data file
        for iteration_count in range(iterations): # for x in range(how many files I want to make)
            picked_numbers = [] # what line numbers have been picked, to avoid duplicates
            smallfile = None # the small file written to disk
            for _ in range(file_size):
                # for x in range of how many lines I want to appear in the file
                line_num = random.randint(0, lines_in_file-1) # the line that was picked at random
                while line_num in picked_numbers: # if the line exists in the file, find another one
                    line_num = random.randint(0, lines_in_file-1)
                picked_numbers.append(line_num) # add the number to the file so we can look it up later
            small_filename = 'data_{}.json'.format(iteration_count) # create the new small file to write to
            smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
            for position, line in enumerate(data_file): # enumerate the big data file to find all the lines we have in picked_numbers
                if position in picked_numbers:
                    smallfile.write(line)
            smallfile.close()
            data_file.seek(0)

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I usually don't 'steal' answers but I think people who come in the future should directly know how to do it. If Nobby Noobs wants to add an answer, you can accept his but I think we should maintain the proper structure of stack over flow

Comment: Guy didn't want to make the answer so I'm fine with giving it to you.